# Go back to original version of Firefox in Ubuntu from beta version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox

In Ubuntu 9.04, I tried to upgrade from Firefox 3.0 to 3.5, by installing some apt-get packages, and there is a problem! Now Firefox calls itself "Namoroka" and the Firefox logo is gone and replaced by a black square in the upper bar and it says it is a development beta version.

I really don't like this version, how can I go back to the stable version of Firefox? I tried `apt-get remove firefox-3.5` and `apt-get install firefox-3.0` and that did not work. How do I go back to the stable version of Firefox?

Comment: How did you install that version and why is uninstalling not working?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way; 
Open synaptic, find the firefox package, press **Ctrl+E** and select another version of it.
And then simple press apply.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Firefox directly from http://getfirefox.com. Haven't had a problem since.

Comment: Hey Iain, I have an Ubuntu-installed 3.5.x Firefox, and I really want to go up to 3.6; any idea what changes the Ubuntu team makes that I'll lose if I update it directly?

Comment: Hi Joe. I think you just lose the Ubuntu bookmarks, search engines and themes. I haven't noticed anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Namoroka is the codename for Firefox 3.6, while Firefox 3.5 is called Shiretoko.
Probably you didn't installed Firefox 3.5, but a beta version of Firefox 3.6.
Check if the package firefox-3.6 is installed with "aptitude show firefox-3.6".

Answer (score 0):

Do a complete removal of the old version through Synaptic or command line. Then have a look at your "Software Sources" and remove the "Mozilla Daily" repository entries that I'm guessing have been added there. The packages available should be updated when you close the Software sources window (or do a apt-get update). At this point you should be able to go back into Synaptic and Select FireFox to be installed, and the proper version should show.

Answer (score 0):

I'd open up one of the GUIs (synaptic or add/remove) for this if its not working, SOMETIMES its easier to get information for some of us about something like a failure then you can quickly select the correct firefox to reinstall.

Otherwise you could probably go download it from Firefox.